# XCode project not picking up CocoaPod configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, google-play-games

I have a XCode project, `Unity-iPhone` which is configured with a Podfile,

```
platform :ios

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
pod 'GooglePlayGames', '~> 4.4'
end

target 'Unity-iPhone Tests' do

end
```

And everything about the `Pods` project adjacent to `Unity-iPhone`, and even the `Unity-iPhone` project *seems* to be set up correctly.

There's a sub-folder within `Unity-iPhone` called `Pods`, with the debug and release configuration files, with basically the same configuration,

```
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(PODS_ROOT)/GooglePlayGames/gpg-cpp-sdk/ios" "$(PODS_ROOT)/google-plus-ios-sdk/google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1" "$(PODS_ROOT)/google-plus-ios-sdk/google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1"
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GooglePlayGames" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GooglePlayGames/gpg" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/google-plus-ios-sdk" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/google-plus-ios-sdk/GoogleOpenSource" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/google-plus-ios-sdk/GooglePlus"
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GooglePlayGames" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GooglePlayGames/gpg" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/google-plus-ios-sdk" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/google-plus-ios-sdk/GoogleOpenSource" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/google-plus-ios-sdk/GooglePlus"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -l"c++" -l"z" -framework "AddressBook" -framework "AssetsLibrary" -framework "CoreData" -framework "CoreGraphics" -framework "CoreLocation" -framework "CoreMotion" -framework "CoreTelephony" -framework "CoreText" -framework "Foundation" -framework "GoogleOpenSource" -framework "GooglePlus" -framework "MediaPlayer" -framework "QuartzCore" -framework "Security" -framework "SystemConfiguration" -framework "UIKit" -framework "gpg"
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

Which, again, looks completely correct.  These configurations are linked correctly from the project settings, but when I try to build, there's no reference to `gpg` at all (`gpg` is a binary file needed during linkage), and the build fails, with all references to declarations from there obviously failing.

If I manually edit the necessary frameworks in the build settings, and add `gpg`, the build works, so the frameworks path, and then before then, the headers path are all good.  But that `OTHER_LDFLAGS` configuration from the pod configuration file is just ignored / never initially included.

If I'm honest, I'm not 100% sure any of the config file is actually work as I'm fairly unfamiliar with the exact way it all comes together.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the error messages are originating in the "Unity-iPhone Tests" target. What could be happening is your source files are members of both build targets, and since the pod `GooglePlayGames` is only included in the primary target, your Tests target will complain because it can't compile your source without the dependencies the code is referring to.

One solution to this is to unmark the source files for the Tests target, and temporarily comment out your Tests-specific code. Now see if it can compile.

Later on, to get your Tests running again, you can mark certain source files as members of the Tests target, particularly code that either doesn't reference the dependencies, or code that abstracts your dependencies out completely so that the Tests target doesn't need to know about them at all. This way you can still share some code between the two targets directly and be able to test certain things that need testing.

The other, probably better, solution is to just unmark everything from Tests and add `import Unity-iPhone` to the top of your Tests's file.  The "downside" to this is you have to then spend time adjusting the scoping of the code in your primary target (i.e. `public` vs `internal` vs `private`) to make sure that the classes and functions are visible to the Tests module.  Be careful with this because how you alter the scoping here can have important implications if you're developing a family of applications that other developers will be working on, or if you're creating a library project that other developers will consume.

Comment: Cheers for the answer, but no, this is 100% related to the main project only, not the Tests one. I thought I clarified that by stating if I add the reference to gpg, if fixed things. Nothing to do with tests project at all her.

Comment: Ah good point, I overlooked that.  The symptoms sound similar.  I recall on a project I've had to resort to using https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate to completely remove the cocoapods-related build settings from the project and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

The gpg.framework is part of the GooglePlayGames Pod, so it is linked into libPod.a.  The Unity-iPhone project links against the libPod, so that is how it finds the gpg lib.

You can see what is being included in the Pod by looking at Pods/GooglePlayGames.

What version(s) of the podspec are you picking up?  If you look in Podfile.lock, it has some info.  My project is working, here is my Podfile.lock contents:

```
PODS:
  - google-plus-ios-sdk (1.7.1)
  - GooglePlayGames (4.4.1):
  - google-plus-ios-sdk (>= 1.5)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - GooglePlayGames (~> 4.4)

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  google-plus-ios-sdk: 47adbe03ea904bdb7aa1c0eca282a23c4686e1bc
  GooglePlayGames: 9102e31d4e04e7a642419fef9a4cf0814a128b7d
```

There also are some troubleshooting tips for Cocoapods: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html

Comment: Hey Clayton, yeah I've the exact same in my `Podfile.lock`, but with an extra `COCOAPODS: 0.38.2` line at the end.  Unfortunately, as I said, everything looks 100% correct, everything in the Pods section like correct, and every library, and framework file look present and all good, but when building the main project, things just don't link up.